# Do not insert primary key when inserting via SQLAlchemy model

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am getting an error while testing my SQLAlchemy+Flask+Postgres app.  When I execute a POST on the API endpoint I wrote, I see the following error in my command line:

***sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.GeneratedAlways) cannot insert into column "rs_id"***

It appears to be attempting to do the following:

***SQL: INSERT INTO ref_status (rs_id, rs_status_name) VALUES (nextval('status_id_seq'), %(rs_status_name)s) RETURNING ref_status.rs_id***

The model:

```
class Status(Base):
    __tablename__ = "ref_status"

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('status_id_seq'), name="rs_id", primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, name="rs_status_name")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Status name={self.name} id={self.id} />"

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "name": self.name,
        }
```

This is the create statement in postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE public.ref_status
(
    rs_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    rs_status_name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT ref_status_pkey PRIMARY KEY (rs_id)
)
```

The API endpoint:

```
    if request.method=="POST":

        name = request.form['name']

        if len(name) == 0:
            return "Invalid name", 400

        status = Status(name=name)

        sesh.add(status)
        sesh.commit()

        return jsonify({
            "result":True,
            "id": status.id,
            "name": name
        })
```

What can I do to avoid this error while still inserting the record and the primary key get populated with the sequence value?  I've tried googling the error, but I have not come across a solution yet that appears to apply to my situation.  My Google-fu is weak today...

Comment: don't make a autogenrated identody field, make it a single  integer

Comment: Assume I can't make the decision to change the database

Comment: i don't get why you made a auto genrreted column if your id is coming from another side.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `Sequence` from the `Column` definition in the model.